# Remove white space/padding in ReorderableListView

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm getting some weird white space when I drag the item to reorder it that is defined nowhere. How can I get rid of the white spacing and extend the card to fill this space?
That's how the white spacing looks like when reordering the item:

[image]

And that's my code to build the body of the Scaffold:

```
body:
  Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        child: ReorderableListView.builder(
        buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
          itemCount: widget.cards.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(widget.cards[index].name),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {});
              },
              child:
              Card(
                child:
                SizedBox(
                  height: 75,
                  child: ListTile(
                    tileColor: Colors.red.shade200,
                    title: Text(widget.cards[index].name),
                    trailing: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                      index: index,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
  ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case Padding appear of **Card** Widget default margin. You can remove using this code . If you remove that not show the elevation of **Card** Widget. If you dont want that you can remove **Card** Widget.

```
Card(
     margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
     child: SizedBox( .......
```

Comment: This is helpful! Is there also a way to have both? Keeping the EdgeInsets > 0 and not having the white margin on reorder?

Comment: You can add a Container before the card with the same colour of child. Container(
                color: Colors.red.shade200,
                child: Card(child:...) . Im not recommended this because app users can't feel the Card elevation.

Comment: Clearly, but that would remove the effect of the EdgeInsets, same as setting the insets to 0. I guess, I'll just post a follow-up question for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `proxyDecorator` to give your custom widget on reordering

result [image]

```
Stack(children: [
  Positioned(
    child: ReorderableListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      proxyDecorator: (child, i, d) { // Here
        return Card(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 75,
            child: ListTile(
              selectedTileColor: Colors.amber,
              tileColor: Colors.red.shade200,
              title: Text(cards[i]),
              trailing: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                index: i,
                child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
      itemCount: cards.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(cards[index]),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Card(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 75,
              child: ListTile(
                selectedTileColor: Colors.amber,
                tileColor: Colors.red.shade200,
                title: Text(cards[index]),
                trailing: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                  index: index,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                ),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  )
]);
```

Comment: How would you access cards if it is a class attribute? By calling cards[index] that would be problematic.