# Remove white space/padding on drag in ReorderableListView

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

this is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217422/remove-white-space-padding-in-reorderablelistview).
I'm getting some white space when I drag the list item to reorder it. How can I get rid of the white spacing while keeping the EdgeInsets between list elements? That's how the white spacing looks like when reordering the item:

[image]

And that's my code to build the body of the Scaffold:

```
body:
  Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        child: ReorderableListView.builder(
        buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
          itemCount: widget.cards.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(widget.cards[index].name),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {});
              },
              child:
              Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                child:
                SizedBox(
                  height: 75,
                  child: ListTile(
                    tileColor: Colors.red.shade200,
                    title: Text(widget.cards[index].name),
                    trailing: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                      index: index,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ReorderableListView widget with the [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget. It will apply the given `themeData` to the `child`.

Use the property `canvasColor` to match the colour of your background.

#### Example:

```dart
child: Theme(
  data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.grey.shade800),
  child: ReorderableListView.builder(
```

#### Result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When moving the card over another card the background colour is still visible, which is not nice from a design perspective. Isn't there an option to remove the spacing within the card element but keeping the EdgeInsets between the cards?

Answer (score 0):

this is done using `proxyDecoration`,
return the default child to fix it.

`proxyDecorator: (child, index, animation) => child`